# Case sensitive path checking breaks Angular 2 TypeScript imports

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I suspect that the answer is already out there since I cannot be the only person running into this issue but I am probably searching base don the wrong terms.

Anyways, I have a new application written in Angular 2 RC4 that is working. Based on some best practices I read, I have multiple routes files in sub-folders (with the components that go with them) and a single root level route file that pulls those other files in. Everything works without any problems.

The structure and code snippets looks like

```
|--Profiles
|   |-- profiles.routes.ts
|   |-- profile-editor.component.ts
|
|-- OtherFolder...
|   |-- other.routes.ts
|   |-- other.component.ts
|
|-- app.component.ts
|-- app.routes.ts
```

**profile.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { ProfileEditorComponent } from "./profile-editor.component";

export const profilesRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "profiles/my", component: ProfileEditorComponent }
];
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from "@angular/router";
...
import { profilesRoutes } from "./Profiles/profiles.routes";
...

const routes: RouterConfig= [
    ...profilesRoutes,
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

However, after upgrading to RC5 (including RC6, RC7, and Final), the introduction of the NgModule file now gives me structure and code like

```
|--Profiles
|   |-- profiles.routes.ts
|   |-- profile-editor.component.ts
|
|-- OtherFolder...
|   |-- other.routes.ts
|   |-- other.component.ts
|
|-- app.module.ts
|-- app.component.ts
|-- app.routes.ts
```

**profile.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { ProfileEditorComponent } from "./profile-editor.component";

export const profilesRoutes: Routes= [
    { path: "profiles/my", component: ProfileEditorComponent }
];
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
...
import { profilesRoutes } from "./Profiles/profiles.routes";
...

const routes: Routes= [
    ...profilesRoutes,
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { routing } from "./app.routes";
...
import { ProfileEditorComponent } from "./Profiles/profile-editor.component";
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
        ProfileEditorComponent,
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        routing,
        ...
    ],
    ...
})
...
```

And this is where things break. When I run the application, I get the following exception

```
zone.js:344 Unhandled Promise rejection: Component ProfileEditorComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module
```

Yet, if I modify `app.routes.ts` to declare the Profile Editor route directly instead of using the `profiles.routes.ts` file, the app loads without errors.

**app.routes.ts** (modified version that works)

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
...
import { ProfileEditorComponent } from "./Profiles/profile-editor.component";
...

const routes: Routes= [
    { path: "profiles/my", component: ProfileEditorComponent },
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

The problem seems to be a mismatch between between the `import { ProfileEditorComponent } from "..."` statements. Apparently, if one import (in `app.module.ts`) uses `"./Profiles/profile-editor.component"` and the other import (in `profile.routes.ts`) uses `"./profile-editor.component"`, then the `Component` cannot be found.

As odd as this seems, this can be proven in another way. As I stated, the modified `app.routes.ts`, which has the `import { ProfileEditorComponent }` and `Routes` declaration directly, works. However, if I then change the **case** of a single letter in the **path** so it **does not match** `app.module.ts` exactly , the exception appears again.

**app.routes.ts** (modified version that *used* to work -- notice the uppercase `F` in `./ProFiles/...`)

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
...
import { ProfileEditorComponent } from "./ProFiles/profile-editor.component";     // broken
...

const routes: Routes= [
    { path: "profiles/my", component: ProfileEditorComponent },
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem using final

Comment: I guess you are working on windows. On linux you wouldnt even get the intellisense working with case-insensitive paths.. and the WWW isnt case-insensitive too! see here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html --> `URLs in general are case-sensitive (with the exception of machine names). There may be URLs, or parts of URLs, where case doesn't matter, but identifying these may not be easy. Users should always consider that URLs are case-sensitive`. So take care of it! or use the `angular-cli` it will genereate everything in lower-case!

Comment: @peeskillet -- I am using final too but I see this behavior with 6, 7, and final. Unsure about RC5 since I did not attempt to move directives to NgModule until 6.

Comment: @mxii -- As I mentioned, this is *not* a case sensitivity thing. Everything works using whatever case you want. The problem appears if the two imports *differ* in case.

Comment: Ok, maybe the components are cached or something like that using the path.. are you using the angular-cli? then you should file a bug there..